# Editing a Pandas dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe that I am trying to edit. I am trying to simplify the timestamp column by removing the date and the seconds so the column only shows a four-digit time e.g. "00:00". So far all I know what to do is use a for loop but I have no clue what condition to apply to this problem

```
              timestamp  date    activity   Id     total hour activity
720 2003-05-08 00:00:00 2003-05-08  0   condition_1 NaN
721 2003-05-08 00:01:00 2003-05-08  0   condition_1 NaN
722 2003-05-08 00:02:00 2003-05-08  0   condition_1 NaN
723 2003-05-08 00:03:00 2003-05-08  0   condition_1 NaN
724 2003-05-08 00:04:00 2003-05-08  0   condition_1 NaN
... ... ... ... ... ...
10794   2003-05-14 23:54:00 2003-05-14  0   condition_1 NaN
10795   2003-05-14 23:55:00 2003-05-14  12  condition_1 NaN
10796   2003-05-14 23:56:00 2003-05-14  0   condition_1 NaN
10797   2003-05-14 23:57:00 2003-05-14  18  condition_1 NaN
10798   2003-05-14 23:58:00 2003-05-14  0   condition_1 NaN
10079 rows × 5 columns

for i, row in df.iterrows():
if row['timestamp']:
    #delete row
```

Comment: What condition do you want to apply? Are you sure you need a condition, won't you be changing the value in the timestamp column of each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to keep hour and minutes, you could do the following:

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)  # this step only if the "timestamp" column is not already datetime

df['timestamp']=df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')  # keeps hours (H) and minutes(M)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here I am assuming that the values of **'timestamp'** column is of type string(Object)

You can do this by `split()` method:-

```
df['timestamp']=df['timestamp'].str.split(' ',expand=True)[1].str.split(':',1,expand=True)[1]
```

**Explaination:-** Firstly we splitted values by `' '` so

`2003-05-08 00:00:00`  is changed into `[2003-05-08,00:00:00]` and then we are selecting

`'00:00:00'` and again using `split()` method on it and breaking it by `':'` so it becomes `[00,00:00]` and again we are grabbing `00:00` part from it

And If the **'timestamp'** column is of datetime dtype then you can use:-

```
df['timestamp']=df['timestamp'].dt.strftime('%H:%M')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a for loop to grab hours and minutes only.
If your column is `datetime`, then you can create a separate column from your `timestamp` by calling:

```
df['Time'] = df.timestamp.apply(lambda x: str(x.time())[:-3])
```

That will return "00:00" format as a string.
Alternatively you can just call

```
df['Time'] = df.timestamp.apply(lambda x: x.time())
```

To get "00:00:00" format of type `datetime.time`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a column, say 'Time', with only the time from the timestamp you can use this.

```
df['Time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.time
```